# The time spent on each vertices for a random walk

Tags: r

I have a reinforced random walk in 1D. Does someone know how to represent the time spent on each vertex according to the reinforcement value alpha? Or maybe the time spent on the visited vertices because, according to the value alpha, the walk visits a small number of vertices.

The thing is that I have the formula that represent the proportion of time spent on a vertex x after the step number n: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYGFA.png)
(with Zn(x) the number of time the x vertex have been visited)

Here is the code of my random walk in 1D:

```
RandomW_1D = function(N,pas, alpha){
  
  d = rep(1,N) 
  nextDir = rep(NA,pas)
  prob = rep(0.5,2) 
  
  if (N%%2 != 0) {suiv = floor(N/2)} else {suiv = N/2} ## the start of the walk 
  
  nextDir[1] = suiv
  d[suiv] = d[suiv]+alpha
  
  for (i in 2:pas){
    if (suiv+1 >= length(d)){
      d[suiv] = d[suiv] + alpha 
      nextDir[i] = suiv-1 
      suiv = nextDir[i] 
    } else if(suiv-1 == 0){
      d[suiv] = d[suiv] + alpha
      nextDir[i] = suiv+1
      suiv = nextDir[i]
    } else {
      d[suiv] = d[suiv]  + alpha
      prob[1]=d[suiv-1]/(d[suiv-1]+d[suiv+1])
      prob[2] = d[suiv+1]/(d[suiv-1]+d[suiv+1])
      nextDir[i] = sample(c(suiv-1,suiv+1),1,replace = TRUE, prob = prob ) 
      suiv = nextDir[i]
    }
  }
  d[suiv] = d[suiv]  + alpha 
  return(list(path = data.frame(step = seq_along(c(1:pas)), x = c(1:pas), y = nextDir),Grille = d))
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Absent defining `pas`, and the unknown `alpha` that may be from an unmentioned library, where do your errors start?

Comment: hello thank you! I forgot to write the beginning of my code which is a function. "pas" is for the steps and alpha is a parameter for my function. Each time the walk choose a vertex, I add a weight of alpha for this vertex.

Comment: If N = 100, pas = 100, alpha = 0, as initial values, what plot are you expecting? and What is Grille?

Comment: And on a side note, and perhaps of interest [Kahn-Kalai Conj. Proof](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2203.17207)

Comment: Grille is a matrix of the weight of each vertex. Maybe it is possible to represent the convergence of vn?